# Height of parent and position of grandparent

Tags: css

I have a child element with an absolute position, my task is to make this child fit parent height and move it relative to parent border.

Here is an example, the distance between parent and grandparent border is not given (padding values are just an example)

```css
.grand-parent {
    position: relative;
    border: solid 2px blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    width: 100px;  // this value is just an example
    height: auto;
    padding: 40px; // this value is just an example, it could be anything or changed any time
  }

  .parent {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 2px red;
  }

  .child {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateX(30px);
    background-color: #00c391;
  }
  .expected{
      transform: translateX(59px);
  }
```

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <div class="grand-parent">
    <div class="parent">
      this is a paragraph of parent element
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h2>Expected output</h2>

  <div class="grand-parent">
    <div class="parent">
      this is a paragraph of parent element
      <div class="child expected"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **Note that parent and grandparent are responsive, so no fixed measure can be used**

Comment: Be aware: `display:flex` applies to only to your styled outer `div` and it's children (`div.grand-parent`). It does not extend to the descendants (`h2` and `div.parent`

Comment: Also what do _you_ mean when you say they are responsive? because styling  `.grand-parent` to a fixed width of 100px sort of defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:relative` from the parent so that your element is placed relative to grand-parent then use clip-path on the parent to cut the non needed part:

```css
.grand-parent {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 2px blue;
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 40px;
}

.parent {
  border: solid 2px red;
  clip-path: inset(0 -999vmax 0 0); /* a big negative value for the second one */
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -2px; /* equal to the border */
  width: 15px;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  background-color: #00c391;
}

/* hover the parent to understand the trick */
.parent:hover {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 999vmax blue;
}
```

```html
<h2>Expected output</h2>

<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    this is a paragraph of parent element
    <div class="child expected"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So what's the problem with just making `right` negative?

if `grand-parent` is supposed to be responsive, and therefore have an variable width, then you're going to have to either do some math or figure out how to size `child` to the `parent` but position it relative to `grand-parent`

```css
.grand-parent {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 2px blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 40px;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 2px red;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15px;
  right: -59px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #00c391;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <div class="grand-parent">
    <div class="parent">
      this is a paragraph of parent element
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, the padding value is just an example, I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

the `grand-parent`'s height is equal to the height of `parent` + 40px padding top + 40px padding bottom

so setting the child's height to `calc(100% - 80px)` would be equal to the parent's height in that case you can remove the `position: relative` from the parent. now the child will get to the edge of the `grand parent` while have the height of the `parent`

```css
      
.grand-parent {
    position: relative;
    border: solid 2px blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 40px;
  }

  .parent {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 2px red;
  }

  .child {
    position: absolute;
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    width: 15px;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(100%, -50%);
    background-color: #00c391;
  }
```

```html
  <div style="display: flex">
    <div class="grand-parent">
        <div class="parent">
            this is a paragraph of parent element
            <div class="child"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

 <h2>if content changes still adopt the height correctly</h2>
 <div style="display: flex">
    <div class="grand-parent">
        <div class="parent">
            this is a paragraph of parent element with extra this is a paragraph of parent element with extra this is a paragraph of parent element with extra this is a paragraph of parent element with extra this is a paragraph of parent element with extra
            <div class="child"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: As mentioned in the previous suggestion, the padding value is just an example. I know those value previously

Comment: @nadhem so what is in between parent and grand-parent of not padding, how is there space between them? showing a snippet that exactly describe you issue will be helpful

Comment: What is between parent and grandparent could be anything, I only I have information about those two elements